# JPanel bounds are not matching JPanel size

Tags: java, swing

In a Swing application showing a part of a larger area (eg map), I tried using the [getBounds()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBounds) method's returned Dimension object and a contains() check **to determine whether a (previously created) symbol is inside the visible area**. So, the symbol's position will be compared to the dimensions of the currently visible area. If symbol's position is outside it will not be drawn in the overrided paintComponents method.

(I also want to have a non-minimal resizable initial size of the JPanel showing the visible parts (named "AreaWindow" in the example below). Hence the overriding of the getPreferredSize method.)

**The problem is that for some reason the bounds are smaller than the visibly available area**. In the recreated code below this results in a blank part of the component displaying the area ("AreaWindow"). **In the real application**, this results in symbols not being drawn despite being inside the visible area (a contains check return false despite the panel being able to show the symbol).

(It seems the button row is somehow part of the problem, as the missing bounds area correspond to the button row area. If the button row height is changed to eg 1 row, then the missing bounds area will change accordingly. )

I've tried other layout managers but have not yet found a combination that solves the problem.

I guess I could use getSize() and just assume the upper left corner to be (0,0) but that feels like a hack that could break later.

The problem is **recreated** using these two classes (it's **not** the actual code, just enough to illustrate the problem):

```
package org.example;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Application");

        // if changed to eg (1, 4) the missing area will match
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("1"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("2"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("3"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("4"));
        AreaWindow mapArea = new AreaWindow();

        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mapArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
package org.example;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AreaWindow extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        System.out.println("MapArea.setBounds: this bounds  : " + this.getBounds());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphicsObject) {
        super.paintComponent(graphicsObject);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphicsObject;

        g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        // this is just to illustrate the problem 
        g2d.fill(getBounds());

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString("Yellow is what getBounds() return < actual visible area", 10, 150);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not really understanding your problem. I see no need for the `fill(getBounds())` statement. If you want to paint the background of the component you just use the `setBackground(...)` method to fill the entire background. Then when you invoke the super.paintComponent(...) method the background will be filled. *This results in symbols not being drawn despite being inside the visible area.* - also not understanding this statement. The text "yellow is bounds" is painted. What symbols are you talking about.

Comment: *I was expecting getBounds to represent the visible area* The `getBounds()` API description states: `The bounds specify this component's width, height, and location relative to its parent.` You add the buttonPanel and the mapArea to the content pane of the frame. So the location is relative to the content pane. This is fundamental to understanding the parent/chile relationship of Swing components.

Comment: That's the problem of course. I should have read the API doc properly. Thanks @camickr.

Answer (score 4):

This, `g2d.fill(getBounds());` is the problem. You don't want to use the bounds rectangle relative to the container for this, which often has its x and y properties set to a non-zero number but rather want to use the bounds relative to the component itself, meaning it should use a rectangle with the same width and height but with x and y properties at 0. Otherwise, the drawing will be translated to draw at a location relative to the container (here the JFrame's content pane).

For example, this will work:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class AreaWindow extends JPanel {
    public AreaWindow() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphicsObject) {
        super.paintComponent(graphicsObject);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphicsObject;

        g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        // g2d.fill(getBounds());
        Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
        bounds.x = 0;
        bounds.y = 0;
        g2d.fill(bounds);

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString("Yellow is bounds", 10, 150);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Application");

        // if changed to eg (1, 4) the missing area will match
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("1"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("2"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("3"));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("4"));
        AreaWindow mapArea = new AreaWindow();

        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mapArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Or you could do:

```
Dimension size = getSize();
Rectangle sizeRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
g2d.fill(sizeRect);
```

---

Note: as per Rob Camick's quite correct comment, if your goal is only to paint the background of a JComponent such as a JPanel, then the best course of action is to let the Swing library do it for you by calling `setBackground(SOME_COLOR_HERE)` on the component of interest.

Comment: Or, you could use the default functionality of the JPanel and do: `mapArea.setBackground( Color.YELLOW )` and remove the the painting code that attempts to fill the bounds.

Comment: @camickr: true, that would make the most sense.

Comment: No, I think you understood me right, @Hoovercraft (but I've edited the post in hope it will clarify the problem for others). I was expecting getBounds to represent the visible area and determine if a position is inside it. The only reason I painted the bounds yellow was to illustrate the problem. The whole is-inside thing is left out since it's pointless until there's a way to know the visible area.